# Are meromorphic functions generally (anti)conformal

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, meromorphic-functions

All analytic functions are conformal whenever their derivatives aren’t $0$.

$x^{-1}$ is anticonformal (preserves angles but changes orientations) whenever its derivative isn’t $0$ or $\infty$

Are meromorphic functions generally conformal or anticonformal whenever their derivatives aren’t zeros or poles?

Comment: 1/z is conformal on C \ {0}, not anticonformal.

Comment: To quote Wikipedia: "the (orientation-preserving) conformal mappings are precisely the locally invertible complex analytic functions", and this applies locally to meromorphic functions away from zeros an poles

Comment: @user513093 $1/z=z^*/|z|^2$. $z^*$ is a reflection

Comment: But $z/|z|^2$ is anti-conformal, and the composition of two anti-conformal mappings is conformal.